# WooCommerce Rest API returning invalid paramter 'shipping_lines' in create order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

Creating a order from php rest api of woo-commerce version: wc/v3 and getting error

other apis are working fine tried with v2 still getting the same error

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$wc = new Client(
    'https://example.com/', 
    'client key', 
    'client secret',
    [
        'wp_api'  => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
    ]
);

$data = [
    'payment_method' => 'cod',
    ....
    'shipping_lines' => [
        [
            'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
            'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
            'total' => 10
        ]
    ]
];

print_r($wc->post('orders', $data));
```

Getting this error, if i remove shipping lines working fine and creating the order

```
[07-May-2019 06:39:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: Error: Invalid parameter(s): shipping_lines [rest_invalid_param] in /home/gathhnaw/public_html/mapi/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:350
Stack trace:
#0 /home/gathhnaw/public_html/mapi/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(386): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->lookForErrors(Object(stdClass))
#1 /home/gathhnaw/public_html/mapi/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(422): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse()
#2 /home/gathhnaw/public_html/mapi/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php(56): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('orders', 'POST', Array)
#3 /home/gathhnaw/public_html/mapi/create_order.php(46): Automattic\WooCommerce\Client->post('orders', Array)
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/gathhnaw/public_html/mapi/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 350
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a typo or documentation error on woo api. Just surround the total value between single quotes and run it

https://www.infocaptor.com/dashboard/woocommerce-rest-api-php-example-error-creating-order